# $watch em Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso que depois que inicio a aplicação ela execute um conjunto te funçoes a cada 20 segundos ou a cada vez q um json for atualizado,no angular 1 tinha o $watch que podia ser usado pra tal funcionalidade,no angular 2 não sei se tem algo parecido,pode também não ser o melhor caminho,tentei com um while,mas obviamente travou tudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função setInterval nativo do javascript para executar algo indefinidamente, por um período de tempo .

Mas a cada vez que um JSON é alterado me sugere acesso ao sistema de arquivos, o qual você não tem acesso do navegador. Talvez o serviço que você use deva enviar uma notificação, para indicar que houve alteração. Acredito que qualquer solução que faça este tipo de monitoração ou usa o tempo para verificação ou receba uma notificação. Eu dei uma olhada na especificação do $watch e ele faz algo parecido com isso (tempo x notificação).

Veja exemplo do uso do setInterval:

```
@Component()
export class MeuComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit
{
    private tokenInterval: any;

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
       let tempoSeg = 1;
       this.tokenInterval = setInterval(()=> this.minhaF(), tempoSeg * 1000);

    }

    ngOnDestroy()
    {
       if (!!this.tokenInterval) clearInterval(this.tokenInterval);
    }

    private minhaF()
    {

       console.log('minhaF executada');

    }




}
```

Comment: fiz deste modo,o loop funcionou,mas qualquer função q tento chamar não da certo,sera que e por causa do ciclo de vida?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com isso? Como qualquer função? Poderia exemplificar? A ideia do exemplo atual é chamar a função enquanto o componente estiver ativo.

Comment: dentro de  private minhaF(),eu posso executar um print tranquilamente,mas se tento chamar outra função dentro da minhaF da erro

Comment: Tem razão, eu já tive problemas com isso no passado... Isto acontece por causa do reconhecimento de escopo. Se você passar apenas o nome da função (o handler), o **this** não será reconhecido e, por consequencia a segunda função (this.algumacoisa) não será reconhecida. Pra resolver isto você tem duas opções: 1 usar o comando bind do Javascript (seria algo como setInterval(minhaF, 1000).bind(this); 2 - usar uma expressão de chamada (que eu prefiro utilizar). Deixarei o exemplo acima atualizado.

Comment: @Kai Algum motivo para preferir `setTimeout` ao invés de `setInterval`?

Comment: @Kai Dá uma olhada no exemplo: https://plnkr.co/edit/uz5YrfHLmKHCLpjrxeon, isso não acontece. **setTimeout** executa apenas uma vez. O ideal seria **setInterval**, a menos que você tenha mudado de estratégia. Você pode alterar o exemplo que enviei no plunker para mostrar a situação, desta forma fica mais fácil avaliar.

Comment: Bem, para ficar registrado, vou deixar esse link aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/127625